# QAudioRecorder crashes on stop

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qaudiorecorder

I am trying to create a simple audio recorder, so I'm using the `QAudioRecorder` class.

The recording works fine but after 3, 4 or 5 recordings, the program crashes when calling `QAudioRecorder::stop()`.

I couldn't get any thing from the debugger, because it's stuck in an infinite loop.

`AudioManager` class :

```
class AudioManager : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

    // ... some properties
      
    QAudioRecorder* audioRecorder;

public:
    AudioManager();

    // ... some other methods

public slots:
    void record();
    void stopRecord();

signals:
    void recordStarted();
    void recordStoped();

    // ...
};
```

here is my record method :

```
void AudioRecorder::record() 
{        
    audioRecorder->setOutputLocation(QUrl::fromLocalFile(fileName));
   
    // to make sure the recorder is ready to record
    if ( audioRecorder->status() == QMediaRecorder::LoadedStatus ||
         audioRecorder->status() == QMediaRecorder::FinalizingStatus )
    {
        audioRecorder->record();
        if ( audioRecorder->state() == QMediaRecorder::RecordingState )
        {
            emit recordStarted(); // emit a signal to the UI
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the stop record method :

```
void AudioRecorder::stopRecord()
{
    if ( audioRecorder->state() == QMediaRecorder::RecordingState )
    {
        audioRecorder->stop(); // crash occurs here, stuck in a infinite loop!
        if ( audioRecorder->status() == QMediaRecorder::FinalizingStatus ||
             audioRecorder->status() == QMediaRecorder::LoadedStatus)
        {
            emit recordStopped();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm confused -- are you saying your application crashes and that causes the debugger to get stuck in an infinite loop?  If so, which debugger are you using?

Comment: This is just a guess, but based on the symptoms it sounds like maybe you're seeing an infinite recursion which then leads to a stack overflow and thus a crash.  If you put printf()s or qDebug()s or whatever at the top of any relevant methods, do you see them getting printed out thousands of times, continuously, just before the crash?

Comment: MrEricSir, i'm using linux, when i want to record sometimes it works for 2, 3 or 4 .. times in random way and then when i want to stop recording the application window crashes and changes to grey and says 'Not responding'  that's my problem it has not to with the debugger

Comment: @JeremyFriesner it's a crash as i replied  , even if i use qDebug() it shows nothing, i think the problem is related to Qt for the use of QMultimedia in Linux

Comment: If you've solved the problem, please post an answer instead of editing the answer into the question.